# JVM has incorrect timezone after installation of jdk 8

Tags: java, linux, centos, jvm

i have a tomcat service on a centos server, and it is a time sensitive service. JVM has gotten timezone correctly until i installed jdk 8 yesterday.

To fix it i have to add "-Duser.timezone=GMT+8" after very java command, which i feel very inconvenient.

I use `date` command on my server and it gives the correct timezone. So I am very curious: 
1. what would cause this problem 
2. and how would i solve it neatly?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here comes test info:

```
[chiming1@localhost test]$ date +'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %z'  
20170920 15:01:20 +0800  
[chiming1@localhost test]$ java  -Duser.timezone=GMT+08 javatest/Test  
2017-09-20 15:01:34  
GMT+08:00  
GMT+08:00  
[chiming1@localhost test]$ java javatest/Test  
2017-09-20 07:01:48  
Greenwich Mean Time  
GMT  
[chiming1@localhost test]$ java -version  
java version "1.8.0_144"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

And my java test code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
Date d = new Date();  
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));  
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();  
System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName());  
System.out.println(tz.getID());
```

Comment: which JDK8 version ? what is your system timezone ? what timezone Java shows up by default ?

Comment: Please provide test case that can demonstrate the issue.

Comment: thx for advice, here comes the test case

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example of the output? If its in format of `2016-07-11T11:01:25.498Z` its probably in UTC time (if it ends in Z its UTC).

You can use `System.setProperty("user.timezone", "GMT+8");` or add it as an environment variable so it defaults to "GMT+8"

Comment: Hi pls have a look at the question now